# Embedding Matplotlib live plot data from Arduino in tkinter canvas

Tags: python, canvas, matplotlib, tkinter, arduino

I've only been using Python for a couple of weeks. I have no problems plotting the data coming in from the Arduino with Matplotlib. However the plot shows up as a pop-window and I would like that plot to only show up in a canvas in the root window of the GUI I'm making with tkinter. I've tried multiple combinations of things and I can't get it to work. If I just add the plot values to the code, let's say:

```
a.plot([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

it works fine, so my main problem then is with the while loop when getting data from the Arduino. I've also tried the drawnow option to update the plot but I get the same exact result. Whatever I do I can't seem to get the plot from to stop showing up as a separate window.

Plot window with main GUI window in the back:

[image: Plot window with main GUI window in the back]

Here's the sample code that I'm using:

```
import serial
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg


root = Tk()
root.geometry('1200x700+200+100')
root.title('This is my root window')
root.state('zoomed')
root.config(background='#fafafa')


yar = []
plt.ion()
style.use('ggplot')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14, 4.5), dpi=100)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ser = serial.Serial('com3', 9600)

def animate(i):
    while True:
        ser.reset_input_buffer()
        data = ser.readline().decode("utf-8")
        data_array = data.split(',')
        yvalue = float(data_array[1])
        yar.append(yvalue)
        print(yvalue)
        plt.ylim(0, 100)
        ax1.plot(yar, 'r', marker='o')
        plt.pause(0.0001)


plotcanvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root, animate)
plotcanvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=1, row=1)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000, blit=True)
plotcanvas.show()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main loop of tk will take care of the animation, you therefore shouldn't use plt.ion() or plt.pause().

The animating function will be called every `interval` seconds. You cannot use a `while True` loop inside this function.

There is no reason whatsoever to supply the animating function to the `FigureCanvasTkAgg`.

Don't use `blit=True` unless you know what you're doing. With an interval of one second this is anyways not necessary.

Update the line instead of replotting it in every iteration step.

```
#import serial
from Tkinter import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg


root = Tk()
root.geometry('1200x700+200+100')
root.title('This is my root window')
root.state('zoomed')
root.config(background='#fafafa')

xar = []
yar = []

style.use('ggplot')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14, 4.5), dpi=100)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax1.set_ylim(0, 100)
line, = ax1.plot(xar, yar, 'r', marker='o')
#ser = serial.Serial('com3', 9600)

def animate(i):
    #ser.reset_input_buffer()
    #data = ser.readline().decode("utf-8")
    #data_array = data.split(',')
    #yvalue = float(data_array[1])
    yar.append(99-i)
    xar.append(i)
    line.set_data(xar, yar)
    ax1.set_xlim(0, i+1)


plotcanvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root)
plotcanvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=1, row=1)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000, blit=False)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! That works perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the other tips, now I have a better understanding how the code works.