# Unable to call canvas.show()

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

**Error:**

> /usr/bin/python3.5 /root/PycharmProjects/Capstone2/main.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/root/PycharmProjects/Capstone2/main.py", line 62, in 
>       canvas.show()
>     File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 353, in draw
>       self._master.update_idletasks()
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update_idletasks'
>   Process finished with exit code 1

**Relevant Code:**

```
# GUI imports
from tkinter import *

# Graph imports
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style

# Time imports
import time

def animate(i):
    a.clear()
    a.plot(data)

data = []

# GUI Set-Up
ROOT = Tk()
ROOT.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
style.use('ggplot')
f = Frame(ROOT)
fig = Figure(figsize=(12, 7), dpi=100)

a = fig.add_subplot(221)
a.set_title("Data")

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
canvas.show()

Frame.pack(f)

LOOP_ACTIVE = True
ROOT.config(cursor="none")

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
plt.show()

for x in range(0, 10):
    data.append(x)
    ROOT.update()
    time.sleep(1)
```

**My Understanding:**

Every second one more data point should be added. Every second the plot should update to reflect this.

**My Thoughts:**

1. From some google searches hint that AttributeError pops up because I am trying to call canvas.show and canvas is nothing but I think my line "canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig)" is correct and earlier lines like "canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=True)" do not cause errors
2. If I omit "canvas.show()" then the error occurs later "Exception in Tkinter callback "
3. If I modify my code so canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=ROOT) and match some examples I've found, no errors occur but the animation never does anything. I couldn't find any documentation on FigureCanvasTkAgg, only examples so I'm not too sure what I'm doing by modifying this line

Full code can be seen here (warning: it's pretty gross): https://github.com/AdamVen/Capstone/blob/fasterGraph/main.py

The code I've based mine on is here: https://pythonprogramming.net/how-to-embed-matplotlib-graph-tkinter-gui/

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I've updated my post to include the best minimal, complete and verifiable example I could. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some parts of the code are unclear to me: The use of `canvas.show()` (which shouldn't even exist) and the use of `plt.show()` (which doesn't makes sense, given that you haven't created any pyplot figure at all)

Given that `canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=ROOT)` is used in most examples, I wouldn't know why not to use it.

The loop at the end of the file doesn't seem to be useful. Instead you have the animation loop to change your data.

Finally, you forgot to actually start the program, i.e. `ROOT.mainloop()`.

```
from Tkinter import  *
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.animation as animation

# Data simulation imports
import time

def animate(i):
    a.clear()
    data.append(i)
    a.plot(data)

data = []

# GUI Set-Up
ROOT = Tk()
f = Frame(ROOT)

plt.style.use('ggplot')
fig = Figure(figsize=(12, 7), dpi=100)

a = fig.add_subplot(221)
a.set_title("Data")

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=ROOT)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True)

Frame.pack(f)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)

ROOT.mainloop()
```

Comment: I used canvas.show() to follow what the tutorial I did. I should not have included plt.show(), I was just blindly following some online examples.ROOT.mainloop() is a blocking method which I'd prefer not to use. I was hoping to be able to call ROOT.update() periodically instead and achieve the same functionality. Thanks for the help, I'll be able to test your fixes tomorrow and hopefully I can implement them in my program

Comment: Can you link to the tutorial? (As [ask] suggests, you should provide the resources you used.) I suppose it's either really old or a bad choice; but one cannot know without seeing it. In any case you may use canvas.draw() if that makes sense for some reason; in the case here it's not required at all.

Comment: If you don't call `ROOT.mainloop()`, you will have two make sure to implement your own event loop. This would then compete with whatever code comes next. For use with `FuncAnimation` I would heavily recommend to start the tk event loop via `mainloop`, else you run into trouble like the one you had here.

Comment: I linked the tutorial at the end of my post, buried beneath my rambling https://pythonprogramming.net/how-to-embed-matplotlib-graph-tkinter-gui/
The reason why I am trying to avoid use of ROOT.mainloop() is because in my actual program I am running a while loop which gets data serially and then I need to plot that data while also doing a lot of other tasks unrelated to the GUI. If I were to use mainloop I'm not sure how to get data and do what I need to do without destroying and re-drawing the window.

Comment: I would see this from a different perspective. Consider that any GUI needs an event loop and it makes sense to start this event loop at some point instead of running it manually. If you then need another loop next to it, either run this loop inside the event loop (usually via timers) or run it in a different thread.

Comment: I seem to have answered a similar question where someone uses a serial connection to get their data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42192133/embedding-matplotlib-live-plot-data-from-arduino-in-tkinter-canvas

Comment: Oh that makes a lot of sense. I will attempt this tomorrow. Thanks a ton!