# Is it possible to copy a live-diagram out of the web and display it in Tkinter Python3?

Tags: html, python-3.x, tkinter, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to write a script, that will gather `particulate-matter-data` for specific sensor-IDs from [this URL](https://luftdaten.info/).
When clicking on the sidebar at the website, [I get the following graph](https://maps.luftdaten.info/grafana/d-solo/000000004/single-sensor-view?orgId=1&orgId=1&panelId=1&var-node=9160):

Now I would like to display this graph in Tkinter, but I have no starting-point even though I have some experience with this library.
I already searched in the HTML-Code (eventually for bs4 - BeautifulSoup)
But if I want to display the live-Graph, this would cause issues.

If this live-graph thing doesn't work, is there a way to take a screenshot within a lib to display it as a picture in Tkinter?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a screenshot of that exact page to use later, you can automate the screenshot-taking process with [webscreenshot](https://pypi.org/project/webscreenshot/) or [webkit2png](https://paulhammond.org/webkit2png)

If you have access to the raw data and what you want to do is generate a graph in your tkinter application, you need [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/). It will allow you to create dynamic graphs in tkinter. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42192133/embedding-matplotlib-live-plot-data-from-arduino-in-tkinter-canvas).

If you simply want to display that exact graph, you can take a screenshot on your computer and  display it with something like:

```
img = PhotoImage(file="graph.ppm")      
canvas.create_image(20,20, anchor=NW, image=img)
```

Please clarify your question if neither of these answers is suitable.

Comment: My Problem is, that i can read out the HTML Code and find my Data, but it's not possible for me to build a bs4 app to search for it, because i have to open a window on the website that shows specific IDs, not all. I want to find any Sensor I Ilike and it's Data. But I don't want to take a Screenshot once, I want this App to update itself every day.

Comment: @5thAveApe I've added a link to my answer. Does it help?

Comment: @5thAveApe Here at Stack Overflow, if an answer helped you, instead of commenting "Thanks!", [upvote it or mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).