# Matplotlib animation in Tkinter TopLevel not working

Tags: python, matplotlib, canvas, tkinter

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42192133/embedding-matplotlib-live-plot-data-from-arduino-in-tkinter-canvas), but my case is a bit different as I want my plot to exist in separate window, so created following class:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib import pyplot, animation

class Graphs(tk.Toplevel):

    sensor_data = []
    steps = []

    def __init__(self, master): # master here is my root tk window
        super().__init__(master)
        self.title("Plot me some data")

        self.figure = pyplot.figure(dpi=150)
        self.sensor = figure.subplots(1, 1, 1)

        self.sensor.grid(True)
        self.line, = self.sensor.plot(self.steps, self.sensor_data)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, self)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=0, row=0)

    def animate(self):
        ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.figure, self.animation, fargs=(self,), blit=False, interval=1000)


    """
    This is a dumb logic to visualise if animation FuncAnimation is working
    """
    @staticmethod
    def animation(i, self):
        self.steps.append(i)
        self.sensor_data.append(self.steps[-1] * random.randint(-5, 5))
        self.line.set_data(self.steps, self.sensor_data[-1])
```

and from main controller I call it like:

```
    self.graphs = Graphs(self)
    self.graphs.animate()
```

So, as animation is not working I am lost. Trying to debug the code setting breakpoint in animate function logic, it never stops what makes me think animation was never started. Any hint what I have missed or did wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found what was wrong - `ani` variable has to be explicitly member of `self`, so line:

```
    self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.figure, self.animation, fargs=(self,), blit=False, interval=1000)
```

fixes broken animation while defined in separate class and presented in Tk TopLevel.