# How to animate this arrow on a tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, animation

My python code below is based on the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42192133/embedding-matplotlib-live-plot-data-from-arduino-in-tkinter-canvas).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import tkinter as tk
import math

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.label_0 = tk.Label(root, text="")
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.direction = 0
        self.length = 5.5
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
        ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        ax.set_aspect('equal')
        ax.set_ylim(-12,12)
        ax.set_xlim(-12,12)
        ax.axis('on')
        self.vector = plt.arrow(0,0, self.length*math.sin(self.direction), self.length*math.cos(self.direction), width=0.3, head_width=2)
        ax.add_patch(self.vector)
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0,column=1)
        animation.FuncAnimation(fig, self.move_arrow, interval=200, blit=False)
     
    def move_arrow(self):
        self.direction += 0.0349
        self.length = max(1, self.length-0.05)
        self.vector.set_data(self.direction, self.length)
        return None

root=tk.Tk()
app=Application(master = root)
app.mainloop()
```

I want to get an animation of the arrow rotating in a spiral. Instead I get the fixed arrow below.

[image]

How do I animated the above arrow?

Comment: You need to save a reference of `animation.FuncAnimation(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've removed usage of Class to make your code more closer to the working [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42192133/embedding-matplotlib-live-plot-data-from-arduino-in-tkinter-canvas).

[image: Clock]:

Code:

```
import math
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg


def move_arrow(i):
    root.direction += 0.1349
    root.length = max(1, root.length - 0.05)
    root.vector.set_data(dx=root.direction, dy=root.length)


root = tk.Tk()
root.label_0 = tk.Label(root, text="")
root.direction = 0
root.length = 5.5
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.set_ylim(-12, 12)
ax.set_xlim(-12, 12)
ax.axis('on')
root.vector = plt.arrow(0, 0, root.length * math.sin(root.direction), root.length * math.cos(root.direction), width=0.3, head_width=2)
ax.add_patch(root.vector)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=1)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, move_arrow, interval=200, blit=False)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: when I run your code I get this error:  "in move_arrow root.vector.set_data(dx=root.direction,dy=root.length) AttributeError: 'FancyArrow' object hanse attribute 'set_data' ". Also the arrow doesn't change. Do you know why I would get that, and how to fix it?

Comment: @TedErsek what Matplotlib version do you have?  Support for animating `FancyArrow` was added at v3.5 https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/18807

Comment: @TedErsek I'm running my code on Python 3.12 and matplotlib 3.8.2